# Variable Will Not Update (Inside If Statement)

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, greenfoot

Working on a school project where we're supposed to modify a game to become educational. I want to cycle through numbers 0, 1, and 2 through the variable moduleThree. But the variable will not update when I set it equal to something else than what I originally defined it as, and it's incredibly frustrating.

I tried putting the if/else chain into a different method with return, but that didn't work. I tried putting it in multiple spots.

```
public class Alien extends Actor
{
    int SPEED = -7; // Speed of 10 in left direction "-"
    int tempType = (int)(Math.random() * ((2-0) + 1));
    int controlType = 0;
    int moduleThree = 0;

    public Alien() {

    }

    public void act() {
       move (SPEED);
       int timer = 10;
       if (timer>0){
           timer--;
           if(timer == 0) {
               timer = 10;
               controlType++;
               moduleThree = controlType % 3;
               if(moduleThree == 0){
                  ((SpaceLand)(getWorld())).pos.swap("bee");
               }
               else if(moduleThree  == 1){
                  ((SpaceLand)(getWorld())).pos.swap("alien");
               }
               else if(moduleThree  == 2){
                  ((SpaceLand)(getWorld())).pos.swap("soldier");
               }
           }
       }
```

moduleThree should cycle through 0, 1, and 2 as it calculated controlType % 3, but no update occurs. Even when I manually set it to something like 4, nothing happens. Extremely annoying.

Comment: This code looks specious; `timer` is `9` not `0`, so `if(timer == 0) {` is going to be `false`. Also, `((SpaceLand)(getWorld()))` scares me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How is timer 9? Isn't timer-- supposed to loop, since it constantly goes when timer is above 0?

Comment: `timer--` is not a loop. It is `timer = timer - 1`; and since `timer` ***was*** ten, after that it is nine.

Comment: @JackTapia you can make it loop by changing `if (timer>0)` to `while(timer > 0)`, though be aware you're resetting `timer` to 10 whenever it reaches 0 which will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `int timer = 10;` line is declaring a local variable, so timer is always set to 10 at the beginning of each `act()` call and the variable is forgotten after each call.  It looks like you meant to declare `timer` as a field of the class to keep its value between act calls.  If you move the definition to beneath where `moduleThree` is declared, I think it will do what you intended.